# LINQ search by multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have implemented a search form above the table which was provided using this query.

`students.GroupBy(x => new { x.Fname, x.classdate}).Select(grp => grp.First);`

During search is submitted i wanted to use one or more search criteria's provided, given any of three criteria's are provided at a time or not, using && or OR would not help in narrowing down result set.

I have tired checking if not null and further adding if clauses but that seemed messy. I wanted to know is there any way to do search using a Model object or any other way you would suggest?

My implementation (assume checked values in the if function are from the form )

```
if (Fname !=null) students=students.Where(x => x.FirstName==Fname)
if (Lname!=null) students=students.Where(x => x.LastName==Lname)
if (ClassDate!=null) students=students.Where(x => x.classdate==ClassDate)
```

Comment: What you have is how I'd do it.  The other approach would be to do the check in the query like `(x.FirstName == Fname || Fname == null) && ...` which I think is even more messy.

Comment: Your approach is absolutely correct, you do not need to change it.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov thank you, i was seeing if i could do it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it using either one of these queries.

```
students = students.Where(x => (Fname == null || x.FirstName==Fname)
        && (Lname == null || x.LastName==Lname)
        && (ClassDate == null || x.classdate==ClassDate));
```

or

```
students = students.Where(x => x.FirstName==(Fname ?? x.FirstName)
        && x.LastName==(Lname ?? x.LastName)
        && x.classdate==(ClassDate??x.classdate));
```

Comment: Second option is easier to read and understand I think.

Comment: @Igor I played a bit with the second one, it looks cleaner, but i had a conversion setup to catch the input date and format it which is giving me error. I'll research further and hope it will workout.

Comment: One more question i think using Fname ?? x.FirstName assigns a key value if null, exactly what value does x.FirstName holds?

Comment: @smned - `Fname ?? x.FirstName` is functionally equivalent to `Fname != null ? Fname : x.FirstName`. That is the value `Fname` is used unless it is null in which case the value of `x.FirstName` is used.

Comment: Just wanted to add that the second statement makes a checking for null queries which caused a noticeable execution time increase on my program with oracle DB.